# R Coding for ggridges

Tags: r, ridgeline-plot, ggridges

I am new to coding in R so please excuse the simple question. I am trying to run ggridges geom in R to create monthly density plots. The code is below, but it creates a plot with the months in the wrong order:[image]

The code references a csv data file with 3 columns (see image) - MST, Aeco_5a, and month:[image] Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
> library(ggridges)
> read_csv("C:/Users/Calvin Johnson/Desktop/Aeco_Price_2017.csv")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  MST = col_character(),
  Month = col_character(),
  Aeco_5a = col_double()
)
# A tibble: 365 x 3
         MST   Month Aeco_5a
       <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
 1  1/1/2017 January  3.2678
 2  1/2/2017 January  3.2678
 3  1/3/2017 January  3.0570
 4  1/4/2017 January  2.7811
 5  1/5/2017 January  2.6354
 6  1/6/2017 January  2.7483
 7  1/7/2017 January  2.7483
 8  1/8/2017 January  2.7483
 9  1/9/2017 January  2.5905
10 1/10/2017 January  2.6902
# ... with 355 more rows
> 
> mins<-min(Aeco_Price_2017$Aeco_5a)
> maxs<-max(Aeco_Price_2017$Aeco_5a)
> 
> ggplot(Aeco_Price_2017,aes(x = Aeco_5a,y=Month,height=..density..))+
+     geom_density_ridges(scale=3) +
+     scale_x_continuous(limits = c(mins,maxs))
```

Answer (score 1):

This has two parts: (1) you want your months to be `factor` instead of `chr`, and (2) you need to order the factors the way we typically order months.

With some reproducible data:

```
library(ggridges)
df <- sapply(month.abb, function(x) { rnorm(10, rnorm(1), sd = 1)}) 
df <- as_tibble(x) %>% gather(key = "month")
```

Then you need to `mutate` month to be a factor, and use the levels defined by the actual order they show up in the data.frame (`unique` gives the unique levels in the dataset, and orders them in the way they're ordered in your data ("Jan", "Feb", ...)). Then you need to reverse them, because this way "Jan" will be at the bottom (it's the first factor).

```
df %>% 
  # switch to factor, and define the levels they way you want them to show up 
  # in the ggplot; "Dec", "Nov", "Oct", ... 
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = rev(unique(df$month)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = month)) + 
  geom_density_ridges()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your suggestions, and received the following error message:  Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')". Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: `mutate()` is part of the library `dplyr`. you can enter `library(tidyverse)`it loads  `dplyr`and `ggplot2`, also `tidyr`which inclues the `gather()` function (used from Jesse in the answer).